# android app in Kotlin keep stopping when click on backbutton on Actionbar

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my first Kotlin android app. I m using Android studio v3.5.3 (AndroidX)

This is the workflow:

(Start)  Main --> goto MainSvc1 ---> goto MainSelectCat ---> goto MainDisplay

SetUp for the BackButton on ActionBar. I use toolbar ( AndroidX)

I add this in : MainSvc1 , MainSelectCat, MainDisplay

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

In Manifest :

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainSvc1"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:parentActivityName="com.example.myApp.MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myApp.MainActivity"/>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".MainSelectCat"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myApp.MainSvc1Activity">

      <Meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myApp.MainSvc1Activity"/>
 </activity>
```

the rest will follow this pattern for MainSelectCat and  MainDisplay

When I click on backBtn on the last Activity

In Last activity : MainDisplay Activity, I added the below:

```
val bundle: Bundle? = intent.extras
val strUrl = bundle!!.getString("CodeId")
var ProductCode = bundle.getString("CodeName")
val strUrl : List<String> = strUrl.split("-")
var Id: Int = strUrl[0].trim().toInt()

val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar?

setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

// Now get the support action bar
val actionBar = supportActionBar

// Set toolbar title/app title
actionBar!!.title = "Welcome"
```

The problem:

1. I implemented the BackBtn on the Last Activity.

   When I click the back btn on MainDisplay to navigate back to MainSelectCat

   The app will crash with this message: The (appName) App keep stopping.
2. If I don't implement the backBtn on the Last activity, When I navigate back to MainSelectCat using Hardware or physical button, the App will not crash and work ok.

How to I fix it for (1)?

**-- Update:**
I use ADB to get log ( adb logcat AndroidRuntime:E *:S)

the problem is : 
the String1 is null when click backbutton on actionbar to return from MainDisplay to (2)

1) (Start) Main goto MainSvc1

pass Data by intent.putExtra(string1) to (2)

2) MainSelectCat

Handle pass-in (String1) from MainSvc1

Pass Data by intent.putExtra(string2) to MainDisplay (3)

3) MainDisplay

problem start when click backButton on Actionbar to return to (2)

How to Fix the issue ?

Comment: My guess would be the force cast on the bundle causing it, but could you share the logcat crash ?

Comment: Please post error stacktrace. Apps don't just crash without info in Logcat.

Comment: Thank you all for helping. Thank for the logcat suggestion. As this is my 1st time , need time to learn to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out, without a stacktrace we can just assume what happend.

My assumption is that you pass data between those activities with e.g. .addString and the next activity always receives that data, unless you are pressing the backbutton. If the backbutton is pressed the previous activity doesn't pass any data to the one that is coming up after the backbutton and then it crashes because you require it at some point.

If this is the case, there might not be an easy fix depending on how you designed those activities. If they don't need the data, just ignore it if it doesn't exist.

If they always need the data, you need to think of some other way to store it

Answer (score 0):

hi I think I found a solution using SharePreferences to store data

```
 private val sharedPrefFile = "kotlinsharedpreference"
```

val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefFile,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

var intent = intent 
 val strCode = intent.getStringExtra("CodeId")

if (strCode != null){

```
//- 1st time is not null, so store it
 val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor =  sharedPreferences.edit()
 editor.putString("hCode",strCode)
 editor.apply()
 editor.commit()
```

}else{

```
  val strCode2 = sharedPreferences.getString("hCode","defaultname")
```

}